# Manipulate :before pseudoclass's background with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen several work arounds on StackOverflow however none of which seem to be a sufficient answer for what I am looking to achieve.

### Live Demo:

```js
var value = 0,
    pos = 0,
    progressHidden = false,
    progressEl = $('progress'),
    timer = setInterval(progress, 100);

var ProgressColourTween = [
    "#ff4400", "#ff4900", "#ff4a00", "#ff4c00", "#ff4d00", "#ff4f00", "#ff5000", "#ff5100", "#ff5200", "#ff5400",
    "#ff5600", "#ff5700", "#ff5900", "#ff5a00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5c00", "#ff5e00", "#ff5f00", "#ff6100", "#ff6300",
    "#ff6400", "#ff6600", "#ff6700", "#ff6800", "#ff6900", "#ff6b00", "#ff6c00", "#ff6e00", "#ff6f00", "#ff7100",
    "#ff7200", "#ff7300", "#ff7500", "#ff7600", "#ff7800", "#ff7900", "#ff7a00", "#ff7c00", "#ff7d00", "#ff7f00",
    "#ff8700", "#ff8800", "#ff8a00", "#ff8b00", "#ff8c00", "#ff8e00", "#ff8f00", "#ff9100", "#ff9200", "#ff9400",
    "#ff9400", "#fc9500", "#fa9600", "#f79700", "#f59800", "#f29900", "#f09a00", "#ed9c00", "#eb9c00", "#e89e00",
    "#e69e00", "#e3a000", "#e0a100", "#dea200", "#dba300", "#d9a400", "#d6a500", "#d4a600", "#d1a700", "#cfa800",
    "#cca900", "#c9ab00", "#c7ab00", "#c4ad00", "#c2ae00", "#bfaf00", "#bdb000", "#bab100", "#b8b200", "#b5b300",
    "#b3b400", "#b0b500", "#adb600", "#abb700", "#a8b900", "#a6b900", "#a3bb00", "#a1bb00", "#9ebd00", "#9cbe00",
    "#99bf00", "#96c000", "#94c100", "#91c200", "#8fc300", "#8cc400", "#8ac500", "#87c600", "#85c700", "#82c800"
];

function progress() {

    // run counter
    value++;
    if (value <= 100) {
        progressEl.val(value);
        progressEl.css("background-color", ProgressColourTween[value]);
        pos = 1 - (value / 100);
        if (value == '10') {
            $('progress').addClass('ten');
        }
        if (value == '100') {
            $('progress').addClass('hundred');
        }
    }
    // update background
    progressEl.css('background-position', '0 ' + pos + 'em');

    // show/hide progress
    if (progressHidden && value < 100) {
        progressEl.val(0);
        progressEl.removeClass("hidden");
        progressHidden = false;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #000000;
}

progress {
    appearance: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 1.4em;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 120px;
    transition: height .4s;
}

progress.hidden {
    height: 0;
    transition-delay: .4s;
}

progress::before {
    content: attr(value);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: .80em;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2);
    background: linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -o-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background-position: inherit;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

progress::after {
    content: '%';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 190px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: .80em;
    color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2);
    background: linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -o-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient( green, orange) no-repeat center;
    background-position: inherit;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
}

progress.ten::after {
    right: 100px;
}

progress.hundred::after {
    right: 0px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar,
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress max="99"></progress>
```

### My Problem

I've added my colour tween to `progressEl = $('progress'),` however it needs to somehow be applied to `.progress:before`

### Question

How can I add the colour tween to my loading percentage text which is manipulated via the `.progress:before` background?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but I get the impression this will be relevant info: You cannot interact with pseudo-elements with JS, however you can use an existing CSS class which you can apply using JS.

Comment: I understand this @DBS, would this mean you are suggesting I make 100 different classes to change the colour based upon the current percentage?

Comment: Well, to be honest that's probably the most reliable method you'll find (I'd use JS to add some generic CSS rules from `ProgressColourTween` array, e.g. `.tweencolour0` - `.tweencolour100`) If that's not a plausible solution, perhaps you would look at setting CSS animations keyframes using JS, but that's a bit of a headache.

Comment: I understand your logic and agree it would probably be the best way to my knowledge however I'm not sure how I would use my variable to generate the CSS @DBS, can you link me to a tutorial/documentation please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to say `$('.progress:before')` but you can add another class for you progress element in you style sheet and using `addClass()`. Or you can do something like this:

```
var porgress_before = $("<style>").appendTo("head");

// And then you can use below function on any where to style your element. 
porgress_before.text(".progress:before{ background: red;}");
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have time to write out the code for you, but you can dynamically create a style tag at the bottom of the head, then create and insert a new rule that applies to the :before element in question.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

This will pass back an index value you can use to look up the actual CSSStyleRule object. You can then manipulate that object's style property like you would the style property of an element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule